# The C language OpenMP memory issues when creating and destroying array of structures

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, malloc, openmp

In the serial part of my C code I am allocating (dynamically) the array of arrays of my structures `CONF`:

```
CONF **conf = (CONF **) malloc (Nc*sizeof(CONF *));
```

`Nc` is a variable that is obtained when the code is running. Each array `conf[i]` has its own size, that is stored separately in the `long int` array `Nc_size`. Then I am allocating each `conf[i]`:

```
for (i=0; i<Nc; i++) {
    long int sz;
    // all but last                                         
    if (i+1!=Nc) {
        sz = MC;
    }
    // last                                                 
    else {
        sz = conflistd%MC;
    }
    Nc_size[i] = sz;
    (conf)[i] = (CONF *) malloc(sz*sizeof(CONF));
```

`CONF` is a complex structure that contains among the other things dynamic `double` arrays. In the next step I am filling up all `conf[i]`.

Then, I would like to modify each `conf[i]` with a function `CLUSTERINGL`, and I really want to do it in a parallel mode via OpenMP:

```
#pragma omp parallel private(i, NIR) shared(conf, Nc_size)
{
    #pragma omp for
    for (i=0; i<Nc; i++) {
        conf[i] = CLUSTERINGL (conf[i], &sz, ...);
    }
}
```

In the function `CLUSTERINGL`, a new, smaller-size array of structures `CONF` is first created, and then populated with a subset of `conf[i]`, and then returned. Meanwhile the original `conf[i]` (and its contents) is destroyed with `free`.

```
CONF *CLUSTERINGL(CONF *conflist1, long int *conflist1d, ...) {

    CONF *conflist3 = malloc(1 * sizeof(CONF));

    for (j = 0; j < k; j++) {
        if (arrayofconf[j][0] > -1) {
            long int NFR = conflist1[j].NFR;
            i = arrayofconf[j][0];
            // if the is closest to the centeroid
            conflist3 =
                (CONF *)realloc(conflist3, (conflist3d + 1) * sizeof(CONF));
            conflist3[conflist3d].IR = malloc(NIR * sizeof(double));
            conflist3[conflist3d].angles = malloc(NBONDS * sizeof(double));
            conflist3[conflist3d].TR = malloc(3 * (NFR + 1) * sizeof(double));
            conflist3[conflist3d].ROT = malloc(3 * (NFR + 1) * sizeof(double));

            conflist3d++;
        }
    }

    // ...
    // ...
    // ...

    for (i = 0; i < *conflist1d; i++) {
        if (NIR != 0) {
            free(conflist1[i].IR);
        }
        free(conflist1[i].angles);
        free(conflist1[i].TR);
        free(conflist1[i].ROT);
    }

    free(conflist1);

    *conflist1d = conflist3d;
    return conflist3;
}
```

When this code run in serial, everything is OK. However, in the parallel mode I am having segfault almost every run.

I would be grateful for any comments or suggestions. My wild guess is that to the function `CLUSTERINGL` `conf[i]` should also be passed with the `&` symbol.

A small update:
I tried to reproduce the error with a smaller code, but it turns out to work stable. But just to be sure that everything is conceptually right and I learned something, could you please confirm that this smaller code is correct. It is compiled as
gcc main.c -fopenmp -lm

maintypes.h:

```
#include <inttypes.h>

typedef struct {
  long int N;
  double *IR;
} CONF;
```

main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include "maintypes.h"
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <omp.h>
#include <time.h>

CONF *CLUSTERINGL (CONF *conf1, long int *conf1d, long int NIR);


int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {

// check that the file argument was given
if (argc < 2) {
        printf ("%s","Please, give the number NA\n");
        exit(0);
}

long int conflistd = atoi(argv[1]);
long int MC = 100;
long int NIR = 30;
long int Nc = conflistd/MC + 1;
long int Nc_size[Nc];
//

CONF **conf = (CONF **) malloc (Nc*sizeof(CONF *));

// loop variables

long int i=0, j=0;
long int count=0;

for (i=0; i<Nc; i++) {
  long int sz;
  // all but last
  if (i+1!=Nc) {
    sz = MC;
  }
  // last
  else {
    sz = conflistd%MC;
  }
  Nc_size[i] = sz;                      
  (conf)[i] = (CONF *) malloc(sz*sizeof(CONF));
  for (j=0;j<sz;j++) {
    conf[i][j].N = count;
    conf[i][j].IR = malloc(NIR*sizeof(double));
    for (long int m=0;m<NIR;m++) {
      conf[i][j].IR[m] = 1.33*m;
    }
    count = count + 1;   
  }

}

printf ("Starting parallel\n");
#pragma omp parallel private(i) shared (conf, Nc_size, Nc, NIR) default(none)
{
#pragma omp for
for (i=0;i<Nc;i++) {
  long int sz = Nc_size[i];
  if (sz>4) {
    conf[i] = CLUSTERINGL(conf[i], &sz, NIR);
    Nc_size[i] = sz;
  }
}

}

return 0;
}


CONF *CLUSTERINGL (CONF *conf1, long int *conf1d, long int NIR) {

long int d = *conf1d/3;
CONF *confnew = (CONF *) malloc (d*sizeof(CONF));

long int j=0;

for (j=0;j<d;j++) {
  confnew[j].N = conf1[j].N;
  confnew[j].IR = malloc(NIR*sizeof(double));
  for (long int m=0;m<NIR;m++) {
    confnew[j].IR[m] = pow(sqrt(conf1[j].IR[m])*5*j,1.8);
    confnew[j].IR[m]*5;
    confnew[j].IR[m]*confnew[j].IR[m];
  }
}


// cleaning

for (j=0;j<*conf1d;j++) {
  free (conf1[j].IR);
}

free (conf1);

*conf1d=d;

return confnew;
}
```

execute: ./a.out 10000000

Comment: Put ```free``` functions ```safe``` by checking them before freeing if not already ```NULL``` and if not, free them and set the pointer to ```NULL```. Most probably one thread frees a memory pointed by a pointer and another thread frees it again. With the strategy above, it must prevent such a case.

Comment: Thank you! I tried but it did not help, I am still having the segfaults and freezing.

Comment: "by checking them before freeing if not already NULL"

That's not any safer. `free` can take a `nullptr` and will simply do nothing in that case in any conformant implementation.

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. Much information is missing to tell what can the problem be. e.g. where `conflist3d` is defined, if it is a shared variable it can cause a data race...

Comment: I suggest to use `default(none) ` data sharing clause, so you have to explicitly define data-sharing attributes of all of your variables. It may help to find the data race.

Comment: Are you using global variables in your `CLUSTERINGL` function? For instance I can't see any declaration for `i`, `j`, and `k`. You don't show the whole code, so it's nearly impossible to really find the bug.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. 1) default (none) did not help to reveal the origin of my problem. 2) yes, I'll try to come up with a minimal reproducible example - very smart idea, but it is going to take some while. 3) No, there are no global variables in my CLUSTERINGL function, only the local ones. The code itself is huge, it is not possible to post it here as it contains more than 20000 lines.

Comment: I tried to make a minimal reproducible example, however, it turned out to work stable with no segfaults. I believe the problem is that my function CLUSTERINGL calls many other functions, and I am afraid that one of those might have a global variable. I decided to give it up for a while, as in most cases I can survive with serial execution of this part of the code. Thank all of you for your hints and suggestions.

Comment: It may be a global variable, or a static variable (with the `save` attribute, or initialized with a `data` statement, or in a `common` block...)

Comment: ...or an "implied save" (initialization upon declaration), which are not obvious to pick.